# How to forward declare custom unique_ptr for shared memory

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, forward-declaration

I've taken the example below from Dr. Rian Quinn's book "Hands-On System Programming with C/C++" modified just a bit. It wraps mmap with a unique_ptr{}. It works almost just like I need. I would like to forward declare the pointer to the mapped memory so I can use it as a private class member. My application is multi-task, each single-threaded, hard real-time with shared memory for cross-task communication. Dr. Quinn has a second example with shared memory that's a little longer than the one shown here but it this one illustrates the problem. The shm_open/mmap is relatively expensive time-wise. I need it to be done once during setup and have no idea how to go about it. I know how to do this with raw pointers. I'm using g++ 4.8.5.

I've tried:

```
std::unique_ptr<myStruct,mmap_deleter> ptr;
```

Which results in:

> ```
>  /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/tuple:132:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘mmap_deleter::mmap_deleter()’
>    : _M_head_impl() { }
> ```

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

constexpr auto PROT_RW = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE;
constexpr auto MAP_ALLOC = MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS;

class mmap_deleter
{
    std::size_t m_size;

public:
    mmap_deleter(std::size_t size) :
        m_size{size}
    { }

    void operator()(void *ptr) const
    {
        munmap(ptr, m_size);
    }
};

template<typename T>
auto mmap_unique()
{
    if (auto ptr = mmap(0, sizeof(T), PROT_RW, MAP_ALLOC, -1, 0)) {

        auto obj = new (ptr) T(args...);
        auto del = mmap_deleter(sizeof(T));

        return std::unique_ptr<T, mmap_deleter>(obj, del);
    }

    throw std::bad_alloc();
}

struct myStruct{
    double foo;
    double bar;
};
// Forward declare pointer, neither compiles
std::unique_ptr<myStruct> ptr;
// or
// std::unique_ptr<myStruct,mmap_deleter> ptr;

int main()
{
    ptr = mmap_unique<myStruct>();
    ptr->foo = 55.;
    std::cout << ptr->foo << '\n';
}
```

Here's a silly example that will compile and run that uses a raw pointer that illustrates what I want to do with a smart pointer.

```
// myClass.h
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass();
    int get_i();
    int get_j();
private:
    void myFunc1();
    void myFunc2();
    void myFunc3();

    struct myStruct{
         int i;
         int j;
    };
// FORWARD Declaration of ptr here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// I would like to use a smart pointer
    myStruct* ptr_myStruct{nullptr};
};
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cerrno>
//#include "myClass.h"
myClass::myClass(){
   // Set the pointer to the mmap'ed address
   ptr_myStruct = (myStruct*)mmap(NULL,sizeof(myStruct),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
   memset(ptr_myStruct,0,sizeof(myStruct));
   // The three member functions use ptr_myStruct
   myFunc1();
   myFunc2();
   myFunc3();
}

myClass::~myClass(){
   munmap(ptr_myStruct,sizeof(myStruct));
   ptr_myStruct = nullptr;
}

void myClass::myFunc1(){
ptr_myStruct->i++;
}
void myClass::myFunc2(){
ptr_myStruct->j++;
}
void myClass::myFunc3(){
ptr_myStruct->i++;
}
int myClass::get_i(){return ptr_myStruct->i;}
int myClass::get_j(){return ptr_myStruct->j;}
int main(){
  myClass a;
  std::cout<< a.get_i()<<"   "<<a.get_j()<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "forward-declare" here. `std::unique_ptr<myStruct,mmap_deleter> ptr;` is a definition, not just a declaration. Where exactly are you trying to put this line?

Comment: Please split your code to .h and .cpp, fwd declaration does not really make sense in one cpp file. Code above compiles just fine.

Comment: Side-note: While *your* `struct myStruct` doesn't require any special actions during destruction, other types might; you explicitly invoke placement `new` to construct into the memory, but have no matching destructor invocation in `mmap_deleter`. Not good for reusability.

Comment: Where is the code that does not compile here?  I don't see `std::unique_ptr<myStruct,mmap_deleter> ptr;` in the code provided.  Am I right in thinking the code provided compiles?

Comment: I added my attempt at forward declaration. In the end I want it to go in the private: section of a class header so I can allocate and mmap shared memory once in the constructor rather than 4800 times per second in a member function which it would currently do in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some massaging your code does compile and work (I added some debug prints to demonstrate it), see the [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5358bd8e7800b3c4). (Also, be aware that `mmap_deleter` doesn't call `obj`'s destructor, but it should).

Given that you use C++14, I would suggest to remove `mmap_deleter` and simplify the code as follows:

```
template <typename T>
using unique_mapped_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, void(*)(T*)>;

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
unique_mapped_ptr<T> mmap_unique(Args... args)
{
    constexpr auto PROT_RW = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE;
    constexpr auto MAP_ALLOC = MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS;

    if (auto ptr = mmap(0, sizeof(T), PROT_RW, MAP_ALLOC, -1, 0)) {
        return {
            new (ptr) T{args...},
            [](T*p) {
                p->~T();
                munmap(p, sizeof(T));
            }
        };
    }

    throw std::bad_alloc();
}
```

You can then use `unique_mapped_ptr<myStruct>` to define pointers to mmapped objects.

See [the example with `myClass`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee2ea1209de3000c).

Comment: But how to declare ptr above main? Make it global in this example but really to be able use it as a private class member. In my application, myStruct is POD in special memory. Could be POSIX shared memory or a PCIe interface.

Comment: @Rob I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do by "declaring ptr", could you please elaborate?

Comment: I added an example using a raw pointer that illustrates what I want to do with smart pointers.

Comment: This does what I asked for and provides enough of an understanding to expand this further meet my needs. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
std::unique_ptr<myStruct,mmap_deleter> ptr;
```

tries to *default construct* a `mmap_deleter`, because that is a *definition* of an object. Your `size_t` constructor suppresses the compiler generated default (which is *good* for you here).

You can instead provide it as a template parameter, which also allows you to apply `~T` to your objects as required.

```
template <typename T>
struct mmap_deleter
{
    void operator()(T* ptr) const
    {
        ptr->~T();
        munmap(ptr, sizeof(T));
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T, mmap_deleter<T>> mmap_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    if (auto ptr = mmap(0, sizeof(T), PROT_RW, MAP_ALLOC, -1, 0)) {

        return { new (ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) };
    }

    throw std::bad_alloc();
}
```